# systemd unit file basic.target showing inactive after system reboot?

Tags: systemd, suse

After system reboot , basic.target file showing inactive but I am curious to know how my system is up when basic.target is dead

```
 systemctl status basic.target
 basic.target - Basic System
 Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/basic.target; static)
 Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2022-06-02 12:59:09 IST; 19min ago
 Docs: man:systemd.special(7)

 systemd[1]: Reached target Basic System.
 systemd[1]: Stopped target Basic System.
```

My unit file after which when I reboot basic.target service gets inactive.

```
[Unit]
Description=My service
Wants=local-fs-pre.target
Before=local-fs.target
After=systemd-remount-fs.service
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=shutdown.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=-/usr/lib/Myservice/Myservice start
ExecStop=-/usr/lib/Myservice/Myservice start

RemainAfterExit=yes
KillMode=process
TimeoutSec=3600

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target
```

Comment: On my system, `basic.target` is still running.  We can see that it was told to stop, so something must have done that.  Check out `sudo journalctl` and look at what started around the same time basic.target stopped.  Something may have a `Conflicts=` relationship with `basic.target`.  Alternatively, something may have a `RequiredBy=` relationship and failed to load.  Look for failed units with `systemctl` and see if any of them are `RequiredBy=basic.target`.

Comment: I have one script which is created by me . When that service is running and I reboot the the system, after reboot basic.system does not gets active.

Comment: I am updating the unit file details of that service.